# modifying a text file with regex

Tags: linux, file, shell, sed, replace

I have a source file containing a specific string, and would like to replace the first (in this case, only) instance of that string with the contents of another file. Something like:

```
> cat source.txt
Hello
KEYWORD
Hi
> cat replacement.txt
Replacement
> <sed command>
> cat source.txt
Hello
Replacement
Hi
```

Is there a way to do this with sed? Or any other editor?

Answer (score 1):

I think awk may do this job easier:

if you want to **keep the ending linebreak** in replace.txt:

```
awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" 'NR==FNR{r=$0;next}{sub(/KEYWORD/,r)}1' replace.txt source.txt
```

if you want to **strip the ending `\n`** from replace.txt:

```
awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" 'NR==FNR{r=$0;sub(/\n$/,"",r);next}{sub(/KEYWORD/,r)}1'  replace.txt source.txt
```

the above line works no matter your replace.txt has single or multiple lines.

e.g.:

```
kent$  head file1 file2                                                         
==> file1 <==
Hello
KEYWORD
Hi
KEYWORD

==> file2 <==
rep_line1
rep_line2

kent$  awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" 'NR==FNR{r=$0;next}{sub(/KEYWORD\n/,r)}1' file2 file1
Hello
rep_line1
rep_line2
Hi
KEYWORD
```

you can see, only the first `KEYWORD` in file1 was replaced. however Awk cannot write change back to the input file. what we could do is:

```
awk '...' replace.txt src.txt > /tmp/t.txt && mv /tmp/t.txt /path/to/src.txt
```

the awk one-liner was tested with gawk. No guarantee that it will work for all awk implementations. you should test it, if you got a non-gnu awk.

thank **Ed Morton**'s suggestions.

Comment: this isn't working for me - that command is only outputing the text from the replacement file, without keeping any of the source file. My replacement text is in multiple lines and has tons of special characters - could that be causing problems?

Comment: multi lines, special chars should not be problem. The last line of my answer gave the way writing changes back to src.txt. I hope you read it.

Comment: +1 but you should mention that this solution is gawk-only. It MAY work with some other awks but no others guarantee that setting `RS='\0'` will read the whole file as a single record.

Comment: Also, the solution is relying on subsequent KEYWORD only appearing at the end of the file which i don't think matches the OPs input - it'd be better to set a flag after the first sub() and only do the sub() when that flag is not set, e.g. `!f{sub(/KEYWORD/,r);f=1}`

Comment: @EdMorton I think you mean "at the end of a line". I think we don't need that flag, since file1 is in one record, (`RS="\0"`) right? I thought the KEYWORD is a line pattern. Therefore added the `\n` at the end.

Comment: Ah, you're right it is all one record so no need for the flag, my mistake. If KEYWORD needs to be a whole line, though, then you need to do more with it to avoid a false match on a line that is `foo KEYWORD`, e.g. `sub(/(^|\n)KEYWORD\n/,...)` I think would do it but then you need to put that leading `^` or `\n` back in the output - maybe best to switch from sub() to gensub() for that and go full gawk-only. Of course, I may be overthinking this - the OP simply asked to replace a string KEYWORD!

Comment: @EdMorton yes, now I remembered why I added the `\n`! without the `\n` the output (with the example in my answer) will have extra new lines. because the replacement.txt has ending `\n` plus the `\n` at the end of the `KEYWORD`, there will be two. I was just lazily added one `\n` into the pattern. Or I could say, the double `\n` is also correct for OP's need? he just want to replace the text. :D

Comment: It is an interesting requirements question - if the file replacement.txt ends in a newline should that newline be reproduced in the output or stripped off? I suspect the latter, as your solution does, but I think it'd be more natural to strip that newline off the replacement text when you read it in rather than to add a newline to the regexp to be replaced since we don't KNOW that the KEYWORD must be at the end of a line.

Comment: So, all things considered, I'd recommend `NR==FNR{r=$0;sub(/\n$/,"",r);next}{sub(/KEYWORD/,r)}1`, FWIW.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, this way is much better! I must update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way:

```
sed s/KEYWORD/`cat replacement.txt`/ source.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: The replacement file has special characters in it that sed is having problems with - I'm getting an error for an unterminated s command. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: You can replace the forward slashes with a different symbol like |, ideally something you won't use as a replacement. Alternatively you can try to escape the string but I can't provide an example until I get back to a computer. (I'm on my phone)

Comment: You cannot use the above approach reliably, don't waste your time trying to peel the onion on the problems it will present. Just use @kent's awk solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat source.txt
Hello
KEYWORD

Hi



KEYWORD

KEYWORD

$ cat replacement.txt 
Replacement
multiline?
$ sed -ir  "0,/KEYWORD/s//$(cat replacement.txt | sed 's/$/^M/'|tr -d '\n' ) )/" source.txt 
$ cat source.txt
Hello
Replacement
multiline?
Hi



KEYWORD

KEYWORD

$
```

Comment: I came up with the same as yours. but this will replace **all** lines with `KEYWORD` in source.txt, which is not OP required. sed can achieve replacing only first occurrence line, but you have to either do some change on the src.txt then back (e.g. replace `\n` with some other char) or make a mark in hold space once replacement occured. and check the marker for all later incoming lines. so I went to awk.

Comment: Fair comment. See modified version

Comment: Why cat? Why insert control-Ms into the output? What will it do when replacement.txt contains a "/"? Just use @kent's awk solution.

Comment: I'm not using cat.  Cat was in the sample to only show the content of the file(s) before and after application of sed.